# Rowspan and colspan problems in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-table, internet-explorer-11

So, I need to create table with complicated system of colspans and rowspans. You can look at that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7y3gpofq/1/)

This is html:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 900px;">
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="3" >
        <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/gag.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" >
        <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/ts2.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="3" >
        <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/gm.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" >
        <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/mp.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" >
        <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/cd.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" >
        <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/43ai.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" >
        <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/fc.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" rowspan="2" >
        <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/diodella.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" >
        <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/ts1.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" >
        <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/kor.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" >
        <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/ic.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="1" >
        <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/enter.jpg" style="width: 100%;" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

It doesn't work right in IE even if I set width and height of ALL cells in pixels.

You can see, how should it work on this screeshot.

[image: ok]

Small spaces don't matter now. I set background to pink and added black border for a better understanding.

How to fix BIG spaces and problems with rowspan/colspan system in IE?

[image: ie]

Comment: the most funny is that I can set td { vertical-align: bottom; } and there will be just space at top...

Comment: Which version(s) of IE are you testing with?

Comment: you can help with ANY idea...

Comment: I'm going to look into this definitely, but my initial suggestion is that you *not* use a table for non-tabular data. Tables aren't meant for layout, so it's not unlikely you may run into layout issues when using them for that purpose.

Comment: yes, I understand table conceptions, but I need really to place images like on screenshot.. and as I know, there is now colspan/rowspan analog for divs with table display(

Comment: It is possible to convert this layout to floats.

Comment: @lenden I would suggest using something like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes.html) for a layout like this.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I've heard about them, but I think it is even better just to use position: absolute and top-left for every image, than user some scripts) it is very sadly, that layout is easy and works in all browsers but IE...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of your layout as a 9 column grid where the content spans 1, 2 or 3 columns. Then use floats:

```css
#grid {
  width: 900px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#grid div {
  float: left;
}
#grid .col-3-9 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
#grid .col-2-9 {
  width: 22.22%;
}
#grid .col-1-2 {
  width: 50%;
}
#grid img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div class="col-3-9">
    <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/gag.jpg">
    <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/diodella.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-2-9">
    <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/ts2.jpg">
    <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/fc.jpg">
    <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/ic.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-2-9">
    <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/gm.jpg">
    <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/ts1.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="col-2-9">
    <div class="col-1-2">
      <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/mp.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-2">
      <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/cd.jpg">
    </div>
    <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/43ai.jpg">
    <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/kor.jpg">
    <img src="http://welb-studio.com/wp-content/lenden-design/pictures/portfolio/enter.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```