# Sizing Issues for Image in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11

I am creating a website for the first time and have run into an issue with the way my page is displayed in Internet Explorer. The page should have a banner with the logos of our sponsors as links to the sponsor's website. It works in Chrome, displaying like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGYM8.png), a webpage with small, reasonably sized images for the logos. But in IE (version 11), it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Peff3.png), a webpage where I can't even see the whole logo because it is so big. Can someone look at my code and tell me what to change (preferably in simple language since I am a beginner)? Thank you!

```html
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=big5">
  <title>LTP | Home</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Welcome to Language Training Programme">
  <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 6.0">
  <meta name="ProgId" content="FrontPage.Editor.Document">
  <meta name="Microsoft Theme" content="none, default">
  <meta name="Microsoft Border" content="none, default">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="styling.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--WHY SPACING SOMETIMES WRONG??-->
</head>

<body>
  <!--UNRELATED CODE-->
  <table class="sponsors" width=100%>
    <tr>
      <td width=40%>
        <h1>Thank You Sponsors</h1>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <a href="https://www.poleungkuk.org.hk/"><img src="Po-Leung-Kuk-logo.png" height="10%"></a>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <a href="https://www.ubs.com/hk/en.html"><img src="UBS_logo_logotype_emblem.png" height="3.5%"></a>
      </td>
      <!--LOOKS BAD IN EXPLORER??-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="chinesethankyou">
        <h1>谢谢赞助商</h1>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </body>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}
h1 {
  font-family:Arial;
  color:white;
  font-size:25px;
}
h2 {
  font-family:Arial;
  color:rgb(0,121,194);
  font-size: 36px;
  padding:20px 0px;
}
.tdlinks {
  font-family:Arial;
  color:rgb(144,38,143);
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-bottom: .7vw;
}
.tablelinks {
  margin:30px 30px 5px 0px;
}
.sponsors {
  background-color: rgb(144,38,143);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 30px;
}
p {  /*line spacing*/
  font-family:Arial;
  color:black;
  font-size:14px;
  padding:10px 0px;
}
a,a:visited {
  color: rgb(144,38,143);
  text-decoration: none;
}
.line {
  margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.chinesethankyou{
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: IE11 is picky.. chuck these in inverted commas : `width=40%` `width=100%`, ie. they should be `width="40%"` respectively

Comment: Also `rowspan="2"` isn't going to work in IE11, see this post on how to fix it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27304336/rowspan-and-colspan-problems-in-ie

Comment: Does it contain any other CSS style? I have create a sample using the above code and my image, the result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCgGV.png). So, can you post the Enough code (include the images) to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).Besides, you could also try to set the width and height property for the img elements.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I have updated this post with the full CSS. Even when I run only what was previously posted, though, the result is the same. IE11 still causes weird formatting

Comment: The full class style also contains the styling.css file content? What is the size of the image? Try set the width and height property for the img elements, like this `   .sponsors img {
            width: 100px !important;
            height: 100px !important;
        }`. You could also use F12 developer tools to check it.

Answer (score 0):

Getting things to work in other browsers besides chrome can be a little tricky. I recommend checking this site out, if you haven't already [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_browsersupport.asp). My best advice is use Google Chrome first and then move on to another browser. Google Chrome is pretty easy to use without having to do anything extra for its browser.

Answer (score 0):

Setting image `height` and `width` will work

```
.sponsors img{
   width: 150px;
   height: 150px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```